ggplot - Single Chart with 2 Horizontal Barcharts With Same Y Axis, Different X Axes
I need to arrange 2 charts with same Y axis but similar to a pyramid plot, but the difference being the X axes show different variables. I have a single data set with 2 different variables I want to use for the X axes. Here is an example:

How do I do this in R (using ggplot ideally, but I am open to other solutions)?
My efforts using cow.plot, grid, ggarrange only draws plots side by side, as separate plots.
Update: Small sample data set added (gene = Y axis)
"gene","mutations","proportion"
"VHL",165,0.491
"PBRM1",145,0.355
"NF2",21,0.209
"PTEN",122,0.199
"EGFR",98,0.181
"NF1",16,0.172
"PIK3CA",91,0.15
"BAP1",18,0.139
"TP53",58,0.127
"CDH1",117,0.085
"MET",22,0.075
"SMAD4",33,0.075
"RB1",30,0.055
"APC",45,0.05
"PPP6C",23,0.047
"NSD1",19,0.04
"TSC1",28,0.039
"ALB",48,0.037
"ATM",18,0.035
"STK11",12,0.033


You can plot both variables in a single plot (or small multiples) by first pivoting the proportion and mutations variables into one column. Here are two potential ways to create this visualization.
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-gene) |>
  mutate(value = if_else(name %in% 'proportion', -value*1000, value)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = gene, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_extended(n = 8)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(fill = '', x = '', y = '') +
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        panel.grid.major = element_blank())


df |>
  pivot_longer(-gene) |>
  mutate(value = if_else(name %in% 'proportion', -value, value),
         name = factor(name, levels = c('proportion', 'mutations'))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = gene, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = 'free_x') +
  labs(fill = '', x = '', y = '') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, 'lines'))


Created on 2024-04-06 with reprex v2.0.2
